# Creating an array of generic type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Let say I want to create an array of length 5 through the default constructor

```
public class A <E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements B<E>
{
     private E[] myArray;


     public A()
     {
         myArray = (E[]) new Object[5]; 
     }    

}
```

Is this the right way of doing it?  I'm confused that whether I have to 
state "Comparable"  before [].   so

```
 private  Comparable[] myArray;
```

Comment: Don't have to state `Comparable` because the compiler enforces `E` to be `Comaparable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that the erasure of `E[]` is `Comparable[]` (because `E`'s upper bound is `Comparable`), so casting an object whose real type is `Object[]` to `Comparable[]` will fail.

You could simply change it to the following and it won't throw the exception:

```
public class A <E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements B<E>
{
     private E[] myArray;


     public A()
     {
         myArray = (E[]) new Comparable[5]; 
     }    

}
```

However, there is more subtlety here: `myArray` is not really of type `E[]`. Inside the class, `E[]` is erased to `Comparable[]`, so it is okay. But you have to make sure never to expose `myArray` to outside of the class. Since it is private, you just have to make sure that no method returns it or something.

The benefit of doing it this way, keeping `myArray` of type `E[]`, over Jatin's answer of using `Comparable[]`, is that you don't have to cast every time you get something out of it, so the code is nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. It will throw a `ClassCastException`at runtime

Lets look at the reason. Because `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`, once all the generics type are erased by the compiler, `E` will be replaced by `Comparable` throughtout the class.

So in your constructor, this is what is primarily happening at runtime:

```
 myArray =  new Comparable[5];
```

Which is wrong and hence the exception.

It would had worked with `class A <E> implements B<E>`

So the solution would be:

```
class A <E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements B<E>{
  Comparable[] array;
  public A(){
    array =  new Comparable[5];
   }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   E get(int x)
   {
     return (E) array[x];
   }
   void add(E b){
     //for now
     array[0] = b;
   }
```

Comment: Yes. But it will throw a compile time warning. Because type is not explained for new Comparable<Type>[5]. And you cannot put type because  it is illegal. Why can be found out at http://jatinpuri.com

Comment: Though yes for your case new Comparable [5] would be more helpful

Comment: "So in your constructor, this is what is primarily happening at runtime: myArray =  new Comparable[5];" what? I only see `myArray = new Object[5];` in the question

Answer (score 1):

As @Jatin has pointed out, you'll get a runtime exception if you cast `Object` to `Comparable` since it's a super for `Comparable`, and as such, cannot be cast to the subtype.

I would suggest you use an `ArrayList` instead if possible:

e.g.

```
public class A <E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements B<E> {
    private List<E> myArray;

     public A() {
         myArray = new ArrayList<E>(); 
     }    
}
```

Comment: why use `ArrayList` when size is constant?

Comment: `ArrayList` has a dynamic size - very rarely do you need a constant sized array. Having the data structure resize dynamically might provide more flexibility.

Comment: Just to let you guys know that I'm trying to implement Priority Queue. So B would be priority Queue